# Docker - failed to compute cache key and calculate checksum error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm getting the following error upon building docker images for a microservices project:

```
failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref moby::wpj9ukdrfh21e1cvpctgp34fc: failed to walk /va
r/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3056715208/target: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3056715208/target: no such file or directory
`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 17
```

The target file is present and has the correct name according to the POM.  The Dockerfile has the correct name as well. I cleared the docker cache. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the similiar issue when build rust application with docker, please check the target folder exists. In my situation the legacy folder is:

```
/app/target/release/alt-server
```

after add the new target `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl` , change to folder to this fixed this issue.

```
/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/alt-server
```

hope this clue could help you.